# ${_+_} in a BSD Makefile

Tags: unix, makefile, bsd

I've found `${_+_}` in [the FreeBSD Makefile](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/Makefile#L201).

What is the meaning of `${_+_}` in BSD Makefiles?

Comment: I can tell you that a _bare_ `+` at the beginning of a command line in a Makefile means "run this command even in `-n` mode".  The construct you found appears to be related to that somehow.  It's possible that `_+_` is just an unusual _name_ for a variable, intended to be set either to `+` or empty (Make lets you put nearly anything in a variable name), but I don't see where it's set anywhere, so that's as far as I can get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`${_+_}` refers to a variable. It is defined in [share/mk/sys.mk](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/share/mk/sys.mk#L99) which gets read by the make process. So user Zack pointed to the right direction in his comment; this variable expands to a `+` sign in some cases, depending on the flags given to make:

```
.if !empty(.MAKEFLAGS:M-n) && ${.MAKEFLAGS:M-n} == "-n"
_+_     ?=
.else
_+_     ?=  +
.endif
```

The rationale for this can be found in the comment for [this commit](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/commit/273eef07a6984e917a1b9593d09fbfd80eed5cfb) and [this one](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/commit/91ae96e9ab60545b12f373666c26846c1980e13c), where the symbol was introduced:

```
Make make recurse into sub-directories and sub-makes when given
two -n flags.  If only one -n flag is given the old behaviour
is retained (POLA).
```